# How to clear stack back to root activity when user leaves application?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application with 2 activities, LogonAct and MainAct. LogonAct is a logon activity which I want to force the user to go through each time they return to the application. I've set **android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"** on LogonAct.

When I first start the app I go through this sequence of screens,

`Home -> LogonAct -> MainAct -> Home`

I then follow this sequence,

`LogonAct -> Back -> MainAct`

Why is it bringing me back to MainAct? Shouldn't that activity haven been closed since LogonAct has **android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"**. I expected to be brought back to Home when I hit the Back button from LogonAct.

Relevant snippets from AndroidManifest.xml,

> ```
>    <activity android:name=".LogonAct"
>              android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
>        <intent-filter>
>            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
>            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
>        </intent-filter>
>    </activity>
>
>    <activity android:name=".MainAct">
>        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
>                   android:value=".SearchResults" />
>    </activity>
> ```

I'm using 1.5.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your Manifest, or at least the element for `LogonAct`, as that would help people spot if there is a mistake in it.

Comment: Snippets from AndroidManifest.xml included Dave. I should have included them with the question but I didn't have the code in front of me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The docs for `android:clearTaskOnLaunch` mention that this attribute applies "whenever [the Activity] is re-launched from the home screen".

However, in your case you're pressing the <kbd>Home</kbd> button to return to the Home screen, rather than pressing the <kbd>Back</kbd> button.  This means your application isn't actually *relaunched* because the `MainAct` was not "finished".  That only happens when you press <kbd>Back</kbd> (or if Android kills the task to save resources etc.).

As you only have two activities in your application, you could set the [`android:noHistory`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) attribute on `MainAct`, thus ensuring that users can never return to it and must pass through the `LogonAct`.

As an aside, it seems a bit annoying to force users to re-login every time they navigate away from the app (for example when they receive a phone call).
You could retain a session token with timeout in your app's persistent storage, or hold a network connection open using a service if that's how your app works — but of course that's up to you and your requirements. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Christopher.

I have a few more activities that can come after MainAct so if I use android:noHistory on MainAct these other activities fall back to the logon screen when I select Back.

I fully agree that logging on each time you come to the app isn't ideal. It's a password manager app so I didn't want to leave it accessible for too long. What I'm going to try and do is have a timer that works in a similar fashion to sudo, i.e. request the password if it's been more than x seconds since it was last entered.

Comment: Ah. In that case, you could add a quick method call in `onResume()` of each `Activity` you have that checks whether a certain time period has elapsed.  If so, then call `finish()` and fire an `Intent` to send them back to the `LogonAct`.

Answer (score 15):

You can do following:
1. set clearTaskOnLaunch = "true" in AndroidManifest, in declaration of main activity
2. in activity that must close:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

so if user presses back - it comes back to homescreen
if user launches aplication again - task stack clears and he comes to root main activity