# Android Activity lifecycle conflict

Tags: android

I've an app with 3 activities

```
LoginActivity
ActivityA
ActivityB
```

User starts with LoginActivity. After successful login, he goes to ActivityA. ActivityA invokes ActivityB using startActivityForResult and processes the response using onActivityResult.

If user presses 'Home' button from ActivityA or ActivityB and relaunches the application, I want to take user back to LoginActivity

I tried playing around with onRestart and onResume. Both of these are called when ActivityA  is reinitialized via home screen or onActivityResult (when user comes back from ActivityB).

How can I implement this requirement?

PS: I checked similar questions on SO and did not find something that matches my requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will redirect you to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2131123/844882). I think it should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your intents to start activity A and activity B, try using the nohistory flag e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);

// do not keep this intent in history
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

startActivity(intent);
```

Then when you relaunch, it will go back to the login activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing this in your AndroidManifest file for each activity

```
 <activity android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:name=".LoginActivity" />

 <activity android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:name=".ActivityA" />

 <activity android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:name=".ActivityB" />
```